# Tensorflow multi-output classification accuracy decrease

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, loss-function

I am currently building a multi-output classification model. The model has 2 outputs and I define the compile as follow:

```
model.compile(RMSprop(lr = 0.0003, decay = 1e-6),
          loss = ["categorical_crossentropy", "categorical_crossentropy"],
          metrics = ["accuracy"])
```

The problem is if I train 2 models separately, each model gained accuracy over 80%. However, when I combined them together, the accuracy is always around 50-60%. I tried to use the loss_weights as well but it hasn't improved.

How can I improve that?

Comment: Can you share complete code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!